Latex-- how does one unbold a cross reference?
I don't know why this question has been closed without a satisfactory response.  The referenced ''already answered' post does not address my issue.  I have no problem getting a reference in bold.  My problem is getting the cross reference not in bold.
In response to one comment, I have edited my original question, putting in the  entire newcommand definition and output.  In a style file, I  have customized a  new environment
\newenvironment{exerlist}
{\markboth{\leftmark}{\large \sl EXERCISES}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
%\setdefaultleftmargin{2em}{3em}{1.87em}{1.7em}{1em}{1em}
%\setdefaultleftmargin{2.5em}{4.2em}{1.87em}{1.7em}{2em}{4em}
\setdefaultleftmargin{2.5em}{4.2em}{1.87em}{1.7em}{2em}{4em}
\setlength{\topsep}{3.mm}
%\setlength{\bottomsep}{3.mm}
\setdefaultenum{1$\;$}{a$\;$}{i$\;$}{A$\;$}
%\bigskip
%\smallskip
\vspace{5pt}
\begin{compactenum}
\setlength{\itemindent}{-0.3em}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}
%{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{enumi}}
{\bfseries{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{enumi}}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{(\alph{enumii})}
\setlength{\itemsep}{3.mm}
\setlength{\topsep}{3.mm}}
{\end{compactenum}
\bigskip
}

In the document I have
\begin{exerlist}
\item \label={blah}
\end{exerlist}

In \ref{blah}

The output is: In 0.5
I want:  In  0.5
I have tried
in reference \textnormal{\ref{blah}}
in reference \normalfont{\ref{blah}
in reference \textrm{blah}

I have also tried replacing
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{enumi}}}

with
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\textbf{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{enumi}}, ref=\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{enumi}}}  

and replacing
\begin{BLAH}

with
\begin{BLAH}[label=({\textbf{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{enumi}}}), 
             ref=\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{enumi}}]

all to no avail.

As is custom here, please provide a full but minimal example others can just copy and test as is. Then we have a better idea of what exactly you are doing.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please do reveal how and/or where the compactenum environment is defined.

Do not add formatting commands like \textbf to the \theenumi definition.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.
